# Creating array with struct in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So. I have tried to create a person with struct in Swift and i'm wondering how to create an array using an instance of my struct.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

```
struct Person{
     var name: String
     var boyOrGirl: Bool

     init(names: String, bOg: Bool){
        self.name = names
        self.boyOrGirl = bOg
    }
}
var personArray: Person = [["Heine",true], ["Magnus",true]]
```

Comment: Why is "boyOrGirl" a Bool? That's not really a "true/false" question. "Are you a boy or a girl?" "Yes."...? You could use an enum for various gender options instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An instance of `Person` is created as:

```
Person(names: "Heine", bOg: true)
```

There are 2 errors instead in your code:

```
var personArray: Person = [["Heine",true], ["Magnus",true]]
                 ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

1. `personArray` should be an array, whereas you declared it as `Person`
2. what you are doing here is adding an array containing a string and a boolean

The correct syntax is:

```
var personArray: [Person] = [Person(names: "Heine", bOg: true), Person(names: "Magnus",bOg: true)]
```

Note that the variable type `[Person]` can be omitted because the compiler can infer the type from the value assigned to the `personArray` variable:

```
var personArray = [Person(names: "Heine", bOg: true), Person(names: "Magnus",bOg: true)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd use:

```
var personArray: [Person] = [Person(name:"Heine",bOg:true), Person(name:"Magnus",bOg:true)]
```

or, since the array type can be inferred, even:

```
var personArray = [Person(name:"Heine",bOg:true), Person(name:"Magnus",bOg:true)]
```